# How CYGWIN relates to the C: drive

Tags: file, unix, cygwin, structure, internal

I want to understand how the downloaded application of Cygwin relates to the "heart"/"mind" of my system. Yes, I am as green as the Emerald Isles. So, please spare me. Let me give an explanation of the chain of events and my perception of them ("backstory"), so that the motivation for my question can be understood.

**Currently,** on Cygwin, I can see that it "sees" QUARKy (my [super]username on this comp]. And *currently* I can see that it (Cygwin) cannot "see" the files contained therein (So there's a, metaphorically speaking: "cognitive dissonance"; somehow it automatically "knows" of QUARKy." yet, it knows nothing of it!). It looks blank when I do the "ls" command when in that directory.

Now, if my memory serves me-- I could **swear** last time, the FIRST time, I downloaded Cygwin (I had to do a... whatever the appropriate terminology for a "master reset" for a comp. is) I could go into that directory and I could see all of my files-- just like if how it would look to me if I went about accessing the files more conventionally (Do you say "Through a GUI"?). I don't recall doing anything in particular to enable myself to have these privileges.

So, in part, I wonder if I failed to download a package the second time which I had the first. I am certainly having much trouble with the packages this second time around.

I am also wondering if-- though I could swear I am vividly recalling actual experiences of mine-- I am wrong that I ever had such an ability. Therefore, I wonder what "special thing" needs to be done so that Cygwin can see the files contained in this user directory. And I would please like it explained to me how the added special feature enables this privileged. I do see that it should make sense that, having independently downloaded this environment, it should not "naturally" know anything about my comp. But then, it is further striking, I think, that it should know of "QUARKy" and make it a directory. Though, perhaps I place too much weight on this last feature. Afterall, it is just a name and might natural default to making it a directory. Why stop there though?

See how maddening this is for me?!!!

```
                  :-(    <---- That's what I look like, from now on.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is not an isolated environment like for example a virtual machine inside VirtualBox. It works on the same filesystem as other Windows applications. Its files could be accessed through any file manager (e.g: Total Commander), and it can access any other file including your home folder in Windows.

Only one thing makes confusion: cygwin uses UNIX-like paths but Windows uses DOS paths. There is a translation method to convert them vica-versa. [cygpath](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) utility can do this translation automatically, but it could be done by head as well. Here is some example:

```
#############################################
# converting to Windows path format:
#############################################
$ cygpath --windows /
C:\cygwin

$ cygpath --windows /home
C:\cygwin\home

$ cygpath --windows /home/username
C:\cygwin\home\username

$ cygpath --windows /cygdrive/c
C:\

#############################################
# converting to Cygwin (UNIX) path format:
#############################################
$ cygpath --unix 'C:\Users\username'
/cygdrive/c/Users/username

$ cygpath --unix 'C:\Windows'
/cygdrive/c/Windows

$ cygpath --unix 'D:\Games'
/cygdrive/d/Games
```